# Zapier Webhook from Mailchimp: No-code way to parse body?

Tags: webhooks, mailchimp, zapier

I am constructing a zap to catch a webhook from Mailchimp. The webhook is sending a well-formed JSON and I can see the data using the viewer.

The issue I am grappling with (since I am new to Webhook by Zapier, though not new to Zapier nor to JS/Python Coding), is whether I can use any type of formatter utilities etc. to collect the data from the body.

If there is anyone who has done Zapier-MC Webhooks work then this will be standard and I'd appreciate some help! Especially parsing out the Groups and Tags, since that is what is taking me to Webhooks option.

As a general Zapier question, here is how the data looks:

```
type
subscribe
fired_at
2022-09-29 23:03:02
data[id]
fe3acf3786
data[email]
blah@blaah.com
data[email_type]
html
data[ip_opt]
98.47.186.82
data[web_id]
343667956
data[merges][EMAIL]
blah@blaah.com
data[merges][FNAME]
Me
data[merges][LNAME]
MyLastName
data[merges][MMERGE4]
1234567890
data[merges][MMERGE5]
123, Main St
data[merges][MMERGE7]
data[merges][MMERGE8]
Sometown
data[merges][MMERGE9]
CA
data[merges][MMERGE10]
93301
data[merges][MMERGE11]
data[merges][MMERGE12]
data[merges][MMERGE13]
Principal
data[merges][MMERGE14]
data[merges][MMERGE15]
data[merges][MMERGE16]
data[merges][MMERGE17]
data[merges][MMERGE18]
data[merges][MMERGE19]
data[merges][MMERGE20]
data[merges][MMERGE21]
data[merges][MMERGE22]
data[merges][MMERGE23]
data[merges][MMERGE24]
data[merges][MMERGE25]
data[merges][MMERGE26]
data[merges][MMERGE27]
data[merges][MMERGE28]
data[merges][MMERGE29]
data[merges][MMERGE30]
data[merges][MMERGE3]
Some Company Inc
data[merges][MMERGE6]
data[merges][INTERESTS]
Santa Clara County Children's Alliance, County Budget
data[merges][GROUPINGS][0][id]
18481
data[merges][GROUPINGS][0][unique_id]
a3d51b3e57
data[merges][GROUPINGS][0][name]
Housing
data[merges][GROUPINGS][0][groups]
Housing
data[merges][GROUPINGS][1][id]
19145
data[merges][GROUPINGS][1][unique_id]
f380849f3f
data[merges][GROUPINGS][1][name]
Los Angeles subscribers
data[merges][GROUPINGS][1][groups]
data[merges][GROUPINGS][2][id]
19141
data[merges][GROUPINGS][2][unique_id]
4c5e21981b
data[merges][GROUPINGS][2][name]
Policy Insights 2017
data[merges][GROUPINGS][2][groups]
Attended
data[merges][GROUPINGS][3][id]
19133
data[merges][GROUPINGS][3][unique_id]
f3aba0f825
data[merges][GROUPINGS][3][name]
Cap Staff
data[merges][GROUPINGS][3][groups]
LAO
data[merges][GROUPINGS][4][id]
19101
data[merges][GROUPINGS][4][unique_id]
91e1c210fc
data[merges][GROUPINGS][4][name]
All
data[merges][GROUPINGS][4][groups]
All
data[merges][GROUPINGS][5][id]
19097
data[merges][GROUPINGS][5][unique_id]
85b3a9c1e3
data[merges][GROUPINGS][5][name]
Funders
data[merges][GROUPINGS][5][groups]
Funders
data[merges][GROUPINGS][6][id]
19093
data[merges][GROUPINGS][6][unique_id]
6fe116e8ef
data[merges][GROUPINGS][6][name]
Budget Center People
data[merges][GROUPINGS][6][groups]
.....
data[list_id]
5dab1432f3
querystring:
```

Comment: You mentioned you were familiar with JS/Python, your best bet would probably be to run a Code By Zapier step to do some parsing. The Formatter By Zapier doesn't have any JSON parsing tooling and I'm not sure there are any other no code options for this.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend JS or Python?

Comment: Either or, whichever you are more proficient in